# SBJSON link error

Tags: iphone, linker, sbjson

I am using googles GdataStatic lib for integrating youtube service in my project. I am also using a JSON library for parsing JSON file. What my problem is when I building project it shows error like  duplicate symbol `_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJsonParser` found. What happening is when I build library it created SBJSONParser.o and when I building it again it create new SBJSONParser.o and the linker reports error since it got two same inputs. How I solve this error? I used linkage flags like -allLoad -objC etc. (I dont sure what is the significance of there flags), and I got same error. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is presumably because GdataStatic already links against SBJson. Can you simply use the version they ship? You can include just the SBJson headers, but not the sources.